# Comparing two arrays with Javascript and returning boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to determine if two arrays (a and b in the code below) are identical.

I've written the code below, but the for loop breaks after it returns a 'true' value for any array element.

```
 function arraysEqual(a, b) {
     if (a === b) return true;
     for (var i = a.length; i--;) {
         if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

I think that I need to run an every() function but I can't figure out how to define the function to check identity between the arrays.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show me your both arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) {
if(a.length !== b.length)
    return false;
for(var i = a.length; i--;) {
    if(a[i] !== b[i])
        return false;
}

return true;
```

}

or

```
a.toString() == b.toString()
```

Comment: The `toString()` method may not work in a lot of cases, for instance `[''].toString() == [].toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function,

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) {
if (a === b) return true;
for (var i = a.length-1; i>=0;i--) {

if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
}
return true;
}
```